# How to set width dynamically for included .html file

Tags: html, css, jsp, templates

i have designed the home page and made it a separate index.html file and i have so many 
other pages,

those pages performs some operation, but i have not designed UI for these pages.
and i have included the index.html file in all these pages.now i am getting the background.

but what is happening is when i increasing the width of the content of some page,the width is getting increased but the width of index.html is not getting applied..

it is looking some what like this

```
--------------------
|   index.html     |
|  --------------------
|  |                  |
|  |                  |
|  |    other page    |
|  |__________________|
--------------------
```

When i increase the width of the other page,the width of index.html page should also increase..

How can i do this

Code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <title>X---todo---X</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="frame">
            <div class="backbody">
                <div class="header">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
                    <table border="0" class="tabs">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="mitem1"><span class="mitem"><a href="#">mq</a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="mitem1"><span class="mitem"><a href="#">mb</a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="mitem1"><span class="mitem"><a href="#">m6</a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="mitem2"><span class="mitem"><a href="#">ml</a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body"></div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

relevant css for html

```
body{
}

.header{
    background:rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.64);
    height:110px;
    width:100%;
}

.backbody{
    background:url(../images/aya.jpg);
    width:100%;
    height:520px; 
}

.footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.body{
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
}

.frame {
    box-shadow: 3px -2px 10px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.mitem > a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mitem1:hover{
    background:#E07F1D;
    width:auto;
    color:black;
    border-radius:10px;
}    

.mitem2{
    background:#E07F1D;
    width:auto;
    border-radius:10px;
}     

.mitem1,.mitem2 {
    padding: 6px 20px 7px 20px;
}

.tabs {
position:relative;
top:48px;
left:-15px;
float:right;
} 

.logo{
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your html and any relevant code.

Comment: Add some code of your index.html and the way you include your other page inside it.

Comment: How do you display the Other Page in the Index Page? Are you using AJAX?

Comment: @FrederikMoller I am using the <%@include file="index.html" %> in other pages

Comment: You say you include the index.html in other pages ? usually you make an include of another page inside your index. We don't see anything that includes something in your html code there. Hence, we don't know in which div the content is placed... even though theoretically it should be in the div.body, considering your code nothing is inside.

Comment: @Lyth   ohhhh, i am using that include statement in other pages...So i should use that include statement in index.html ?

Comment: So you're telling me this is actually good old fashioned ASP?

Comment: Well, it's what a template is for. You make one template in which you can include different pages depending on the situation. Your server renders the template with the given content... in your case the template would be index.html and the content "other page". You would need something like <div class="body"> <?php echo $content ?> </div> for an example in php.

Comment: Anyway... if you include your Other Page in your Index Page, you can just set its width property to auto. The Other PAge should then have a width eg. 800px. also, the included page position property should not be Absolute or Fixed. That way you will be able so size both by just changing the width of the Other Page.

Comment: Then you probably need to do more research on JSP. I don't remember right now how to use templates with JSP. Also, your question is more about "jsp templates" than javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone.. :) 
I finally found the solution using jquery...

actually the jsp page contains the table that extends dynamically..

when table dynamically increases, the height of background should also increase..

so i thought of using jquery to set background height dynamically

the algorithm i used is:

```
on document ready

    step-1 > get the height of particular table 

     step-2 > add some default given value with height value

       step-3 > get the added value and set that value to reset the background height..

    it worked quite really good....
```

and same i applied to width also, with some minor changes.....

working really good...

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JSP 'foendi', but it all comes down to html and css and knowing how it works to get the layout right.

It sounds to me that your index page has a fixed width.

To solve this, this is how I would go around it:

1. Make sure your index page has a width whose property is set to auto.
   Note that the included page will determine the width of both then, if the included page is not absolute or           fixed.

Other things to note:

1. If no included page has a width or any content, it may not show anything, because then the width would be 0.
2. you can set the padding-left and padding-right of the index page where the other page is being inserted. for it to look better, else it will look like one thing. this is just a tip.
3. I would recommend to give the index page a fixed width where you just load the other pages into the div or whatever tag you want to change. you have to fit the other page in. make it fit in.